# mysql: add foreign key after table creation

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am quite new at mysql.

I am trying to add a foreign key after having created two tables.

Here are the query used to create the tables

```
CREATE TABLE Categorie_article (
    categorie_id INT UNSIGNED,
    article_id INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (categorie_id, article_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Article (
   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
   titre VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
   texte LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
   extrait TEXT,
   FULLTEXT KEY (texte),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and here is the query used to create the foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER Categorie_article ADD CONSTRAINT fk_categorie_article FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES Article(id);
```

And here is the message I got :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Categorie_article 
>       ADD CONSTRAINT fk_categorie_article FOREIGN KEY (article_' at line 1

Can please someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I tried to look up at others similar questions but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance ;-)!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `ALTER TABLE <table_name>` not just `ALTER <table_name>`.

So try:

```
ALTER TABLE Categorie_article ADD CONSTRAINT fk_categorie_article FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES Article(id);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b786f2a190b45d5290cffc706b5f0b62)